# Coffeescript Support Missing for Aptana 3.6.1

Tags: coffeescript, aptana

I recently installed Aptana 3.6.1 on my new MacBook Pro running OSX Yosemite.  For some reason, it doesn't seem to have coffeescript support like it did on my other MacBook with Aptana 3.6.0 running OSX Mavericks.

I can't seem to find it in a Google search, but was Coffeescript support removed from Aptana Studio 3 in version 3.6.1?  If Coffeescript support should still be in Aptana 3.6.1, then how do I enable it, or what issues might cause it to be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had this problem for all too long and waited for a fix. Today I gave up and installed an older version (3.4.2) where coffee works as it should. Here's the link to the different versions of Aptana: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aptana.mirror/files/

Comment: Thanks @Marcus for your personal experience.  Good to at least hear that I'm not the only one with this experience.

Comment: Me too, and I also lost my command-/ commenting.

Comment: I have since switched to RubyMine, which seems to suit my needs a little better, in case that helps anyone.